# <a> onclick not clickable without href

Tags: html

```
  <a class="btn2" onclick="alertbox()">link </a>  
    <script> 
    function alertbox()  {
       alert("alert box"); 
    } 
    </script>
```

I have tried to use the css below to try and fix it but that does not make it clickable it only changes the cursor

```
    .btn2 {
        cursor: pointer; 
    }
```

but that only changes the cursor when i hover over it and dont make it actually clickable

sorry if really obvious answer only recently i started to do html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some text to `<a>` and it works:

```css
.btn2 {
cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<a class="btn2" onclick=alertbox();>Link</a>  
<script> 
  function alertbox()  {
        alert("alert box")}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a > in the anchor tag
and a } at the end of your function

```
 <a class="btn2" onclick=alertbox()>button </a>  
    <script> function alertbox() {
        alert("alert box");
    }
    </script>
```